# Ionic 3: Ionic Storage with Observables

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs

I have CustomerPage, CustomerService and AuthService.

In need to pass an access_token from AuthService to CustomerService for http-get request.
AuthService and CustomerService are not working.

Please help me!

Thnx.

CustomerPage:

```
this.customerService.getCustomersDashboard()
      .subscribe(....)
```

CustomerService:

```
getCustomersDashboard(): Observable<any> {
      var url = "......";
    let authHeader = this.authservice.getAuthHeaders();  // HttpHeader with access_token

    return this.http.get(url, { headers: authHeader }).pipe(
      map((resp: Response) => {
        let response = this.extractData(resp);
        return response;
      }));
```

AuthService:
is not working !!!

```
 getAuthHeaders(){
    const authtoken = Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get(`access_token`));

    return new HttpHeaders({ 'authorization': authtoken });  // => **not working**
  }
```

Comment: Is your storage API promise based? If it is async -- you can't just pass it to the headers. Use `switchMap` to read value from the storage and switch to the http-get. If it is sync -- then you dont need a `fromPromise` there.

Comment: Ionic storage is promise based ! Can you provide pseudo-code with switchMap? Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read async data and **then** make a request with it — use a [`switchMap`](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/switchMap/) operator

```js
getCustomersDashboard() {
  const url = '//...';
  // read data from storage
  return from(this.storage.get('access_token')).pipe(
    // now switch to a http-get request
    switchMap(access_token => {
      // make a HttpHeaders from it
      const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'authorization': access_token });
      return this.http.get(url, { headers })
    }),
    // here you'll have your request results
    map(response =>
      this.extractData(response)
    )
  )
}
```

Note that `fromPromise` is now just [`from`](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/fromPromise/).

Hope this helps

Comment: Not working, "The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to methods 'this' of type 'Observable<{}>'

Comment: @Alexander, its hard to understand what this error indicates. What line it is?

Comment: all lines in switchMap

Comment: @Alexander, hmm,  I'm not sure why TS might complain there (apart from my misspelling access_token). Could you create a stackblitz for this? Its was rather a pseudocode.

Comment: @Alexander, what version of `rxjs` you have installed locally? If its `<5.5` then use `.switchMap().map()` instead of `.pipe( switchMap(), map() )`

Comment: @Alexander heres an [updated stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ggjzo9)

Comment: @Alexander, awesome! Please, don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

**you can use this:**

```
this.local.get('access_token');
```

### or else you can use these methods:

**for setting the token:**

```
this.local = new Storage(LocalStorage);
this.local.set("YourTokenValue", this.access_token);
```

**for Getting the token:**

```
toCheckStatus();
function toCheckStatus()
{
    self.local = new Storage(LocalStorage);
    self.local.get('access_token').then((token) => 
    {
        console.log("token", token);
    });
}
```